# Spring MVC: how can I give the <form:textarea /> tag a default value?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I have a problem with giving the `<form:textarea />` tag a default value.
When I created a JSP file as follows:

```
<form:textarea path="Content" id="my-text-box" />${content}
```

JSP parser translates the above line to:

```
<textarea id="my-text-box" name="Content"></textarea>third hello world!
```

Also, giving the `value` attribute does not work.

```
<form:textarea value="${content}" path="Content" id="my-text-box" />
```

JSP gives me as HTML output:

```
<textarea id="my-text-box" name="Content" value="third hello world!"></textarea>
```

You can see the `<textarea>` tag does not have the `value` attribute.

How can I pass a default value to `<form:textarea>` tag?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring form tags are for data binding (e.g. your model attributes are bind to the form via `path` attribute of the form). If you need to specify defaults, then set the `Content` attribute of the `ModelYouArePassingToView` to the desired default value in the controller before it gets to the view.

If your using Spring MVC and `@RequestMapping`, a really good place for this in your controller would be your [`@ModelAttribute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html) method. For example:

```
@ModelAttribute("modelYouArePassingToView")
public ModelYouArePassingToView createDefault() {
   //construct it with default values for "Content" 
   //attribute, and it will show up in textarea after the bindind
   ModelYouArePassingToView myapv = new ModelYouArePassingToView(); 
   myapv.setContent(..); //default value
   return myapv;
}
```

In your form, make sure to include the `modelAttribute` tag attribute:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="modelYouArePassingToView" ...>
  <form:textarea path="content" ..>
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar situation. The below code:

```
<form:textarea path="Content" id="my-text-box">${content}</form:textarea>
```

Worked out for me.

Comment: In Spring 4, the `form:textarea` tag must be empty.

Comment: for the latest stable release Spring 5, this is the correct solution. On a related note, I had issues (spilling HTML code all over the place) when not using an explicit closing tag (<textarea .../> vs. <textarea></textarea>...

Answer (score 1):

This works in Spring 4 where the form:textarea tag must be empty:

`<form:textarea path="content" value="${Object.content}"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JS along with Spring MVC to make this work. This is what I did:

1. Change your textarea to basic html as below:

   ```
    <textarea id="myTextArea" onchange="here();">${content}</textarea>
     OR
    <textarea id="myTextArea" onchange="here();">third hello world!</textarea>
   ```
2. Add a hidden input field, using spring mvc:

   ```
   <form:input type="hidden" id="content" path="Content" value="third hello world!"/>
   ```
3. Add the following JavaScript:

   ```
   <script>
     var text1 = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
     function here() {
        text1 = document.getElementById('myTextArea').value;
        document.getElementById("content").value = text1;
     }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use placeholder.

```
            <form:textarea
                            id="id"
                            class="class"
                            path="path"
                            placeholder="test"/>
```

Comment: The value of attribute `placeholder` will only be shown inside the text area as a hint, but does not constitute real content.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the defaul text in the Model as well. Your jsp would have:

```
<form:textarea path="my-text-box" rows="20" cols="100" cssClass="rounded"/>
```

and then in the Model, you'd have:

```
private static final String DEFAULT_textareacontent = "Hello World";
private String my-text-box = DEFAULT_textareacontent;
```

Not sure if this is a best practice or not, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use jquery to get the model attribute value and set the value in textarea**

```
 $( function() {
         var example = parseInt('${example}');       
         $("#bot").val(example); 
    } );
```