# Spring Form Tag removes empty placeholder attribute

Tags: spring, forms, tags, placeholder

While using following tag:

```
  <form:textarea path="message" cols="20" rows="5" placeholder="${message}"/>
```

I realized that if "message" can't be resolved and is therefore empty it seems that spring removes the placeholder attribute completly instead of setting it to *placeholder=""* or something.

Is this a known behaviour of spring form tags? Or do I miss something special here?

Comment: Look at to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24484798/6296931)

Answer (score 0):

> I realized that if "message" can't be resolved and is therefore empty
>   it seems that spring removes the placeholder attribute completly
>   instead of setting it to placeholder="" or something.

I  think that was the expected behaviour of HTML. It has nothing to do with spring.

Try replacing place holder with empty in HTML page to observe the same behaviour. You can [try here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_placeholder)

Comment: <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="20" class="jqtransformdone"></textarea>

This is the output - in your example the placeholder attribute at least exists and would at least have a value of "" - but an placeholder that really does not exists is something else here. And thats what spring form tags seems to do - remove the placeholder if it cannot resolve the expression to give the placeholder a value