# How to capture HTML tags for input/textarea in the JSP?

Tags: html, jsp

When I write `<b>test</b>` in the input in the JSP, the method GET only collects "test", without tags.

**How could I read those tags?**

Comment: can you put your code like that we cant help you!

Comment: can you  show some code you have written so far

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using taglibs in JSP. You must use inputs in form objects only. 
Use like this...

```
'<form:textarea id="id_textarea" class="ClassName" path="path" placeholder="test"/>'
```

For more, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24484798/spring-mvc-how-can-i-give-the-formtextarea-tag-a-default-value)